# Increase and decrease font size for all elements inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making an eBook reader for windows phone 8.1 by executing JavaScript in Webview control. I need help with increasing and decreasing font size on change of slider in app which will execute JavaScript functions in the HTML.

I need all the elements inside the div 'reader' to increase and decrease using 
JavaScript function. Now the problem is I want them to increase proportionally.

Something like

```
function buttonclick()
{
    document.getElementById("reader").style.transform = scale(0.8, 0.8);
}
```

JS fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/0vz43waw/

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Link for the project, along with the js and css.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B149D3iLIyumam1JTlNLNmdoaW8?usp=sharing

Comment: Would you like to go for JQuery function?? I think it'll be better for you.

Comment: Anything is fine. Just need an elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. It will help you

```js
$(function() {
  $("#increase").click(function() {
    $("div").children().each(function() {
      var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
      size = size + 1 + "px";
      $(this).css({
        'font-size': size
      });
    });
  });
});
$(function() {
  $("#decrease").click(function() {
    $("div").children().each(function() {
      var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
      size = size - 1 + "px";
      $(this).css({
        'font-size': size
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.p{ font-size:12px }
.div{ font-size:20px }
.pre{ font-size:16px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="increase" value="Increase">
<input type="button" id="decrease" value="Decrease">
<div id="maindiv">
  <p class='p'>Paragraph Content</p>
  <div class='div'>Div Content</div>
  <pre class='pre'>Pre Content</pre>
</div>
```

Happy Coding....

Comment: Hi Yash, I tried using your answer. It didn't work. Nothing really happens

Comment: Could you please look at the google drive project and try it there. I did with no luck :/ thanks much

Comment: Can't get what you are trying to say is??

Comment: I'm saying your solution didn't work for my project. There's a google drive link in my question. Please get the project from there and try implementing it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple minimal sample demo that you can refer/use:

```js
$('.up').on('click', function() {
  $('.content').animate({
    'font-size': '+=1'
  });
});

$('.down').on('click', function() {
  $('.content').animate({
    'font-size': '-=1'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="up">Increase</button></br>
<button class="down">Decrease</button>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam mattis, tellus id bibendum finibus, elit est malesuada mi, eget dictum turpis nisl ac mauris. Nam auctor elit ut ipsum rutrum, ut molestie erat cursus. Donec convallis mattis neque ut placerat.
    Donec molestie mi vitae velit cursus, in accumsan lorem sollicitudin. Fusce nec risus ac lectus dictum rutrum ac vitae est. Nullam consectetur placerat felis, sit amet rhoncus urna molestie et. Mauris blandit accumsan ante eu vulputate. Vestibulum
    eget porta lectus. Aenean tempus urna a leo accumsan, at viverra ex semper.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use [percentual values](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-size/).

```
.element {
  font-size: 110%;
}
```

Comment: Would it work for all elements in the div? Irrespective of their size?

Comment: if you are using em, or px, as you can see in the codepen  of the demo

Comment: Tried your code, it just increases the zoom level. No impact on font size

Comment: as i see, will impact in font-size, not?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: yes, i've seen, the manual is not good. so then use em,  is the percentual pixels

Comment: I've added a link to the project, Please try and run that

Comment: please put a fiddle or codepen, or any wich run to saw it

Comment: Hi, fiddle and codepen don't support the library I'm using. There's a link in the google drive, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: wich lib is not supported?

Comment: Monocle monocore.js

Comment: @Singhal2 You can refer my answer too. If it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code. Html

```
<div>The text in <span>12</span>px: this is the size</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="range" min="10" max="40">
```

Javascript.

```
$('input').on('change', function () {
var v = $(this).val();
$('div').css('font-size', v + 'px')
$('span').html(v);
});
```

Sample is in this site http://jsfiddle.net/vNfh2/1/

Comment: If I have multiple elements having multiple font sizes in a div (div with ID reader in fiddle provided), this would bring them to same size.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use awesome JS libery call `fittextjs`

[fittextjs](http://fittextjs.com/)

Comment: I've checked that. It isn't for handling multiple sized text

Comment: Please go through it's documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tn74ozbc/1/)

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id='reader'>The text in <span>12</span>px: this is the size</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id='size' style='display:none'>16</p>
    <input type='button' id='button1' value='Increase Size' />
    <input type='button' id='button2' value='Decrease Size' />

    $('#button1').click(function(){
      var size= parseInt($('#size').text());
      size=size+1;
      $('#size').text(size);
      $('#reader').css('font-size',size+'px');
   });
   $('#button2').click(function(){
      var size= parseInt($('#size').text());
      size=size-1;
      $('#size').text(size);
      $('#reader').css('font-size',size+'px');
   });
```

Comment: Yeah but I need to keep increasing the size by keep calling the function

Comment: No I'm sorry but this won't work. The elements inside the main div are of different sizes hence they have to increase proportionally.

Comment: @Singhal2 Hi try this jsfiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/tn74ozbc/3/  . Now all the inner elements will also increment in size.

Comment: Hi, this looks good but there's still a problem. The library (Monocle) makes the whole page zoom in. Download the whole folder from google driver link in question and try running it. I will be rendering webview on phone, hence need the size fixed.